# How to view button top of the tableview?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a table view on the pure code. I created a button in my storyboard. But when run the application button is not displayed. How to view button on the tableView?

Comment: Try this after creating tableview or in viewDidAppear `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourButton)`

Comment: woowww...thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `bringSubview` to show your `UIButton` top of your `UITableView` like below.

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(YOUR_BUTTON)
```

I hope this will help you.